# How to make aggregator wait for response from all methods in publish-subsribe channel?

Tags: spring-integration

I have used the below spring configuration to combine results from publish subscribe channel using aggregator. But the aggregator populates response only from the first service activator in the publish subscribe channel and it does not wait for the response from the other service activators. How should i modify my configuration to make the aggregator wait for response from all 4 service activators?

```
<int:bridge id="ValidationsBridge" input-channel="RequestChannel" output-channel="bridgeOutputChannel"></int:bridge>

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="bridgeOutputChannel"  apply-sequence="true" />
        <int:service-activator input-channel="bridgeOutputChannel" output-channel="aggregatorInput"
        method="populateResponse1" ref="WebServiceImpl" >
    </int:service-activator>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="bridgeOutputChannel" method="populateResponse2" ref="WebServiceImpl" output-channel="aggregatorInput"
    >
    </int:service-activator>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="bridgeOutputChannel" method="populateResponse3" ref="WebServiceImpl" output-channel="aggregatorInput"
    >
    </int:service-activator>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="bridgeOutputChannel" method="populateResponse4" ref="WebServiceImpl" output-channel="aggregatorInput"
    >
    </int:service-activator>

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="4" keep-alive="20"/> 

    <int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatorInput" output-channel="aggregatorOutput" ref="vehicleAggregator"   method="populateResponse"
     ></int:aggregator>


    <int:service-activator id="processorServiceActivator" input-channel="aggregatorOutput" ref="Processor" method="mapResponse"  output-channel="ResponseChannel"/> 


     <int:channel id="bridgeOutputChannel" />
     <int:channel id="aggregatorInput" />
    <int:channel id="aggregatorOutput" /> 

  </beans>
```

Below is a snippet from my aggregator

```
public Message<?> populateResponse(Collection<Message<?>> message){
        MessageBuilder<?> MsgBuilder =null;
        MsgBuilder=MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.iterator().next().getPayload());
        for (Message<?> message2 : message) {

            if(null!=message2.getHeaders().get(Constants.RESPONSE1)){
                MsgBuilder.setHeader(Constants.RESPONSE1, message2.getHeaders().get(Constants.RESPONSE1));
            }
            if(null!=message2.getHeaders().get(Constants.RESPONSE2)){
                MsgBuilder.setHeader(Constants.RESPONSE2, message2.getHeaders().get(Constants.RESPONSE2));
            }
                    }
        return (Message<?>) MsgBuilder.build();
    }
```

Comment: You need to show the code in `populateResponse`.

Comment: In populateResponse the input is a Collection<Message<?>> and i return a Message<?> after retriving all headers from the collection and populating in the response message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `apply-sequence="true"` on that publish-subscribe-channel (which should be there by default) and don't use any `correlation` options on the aggregator - just rely on the default `correlationKey` header populated by that `apply-sequence`.

Having the correlation strategy based on the message id (your code), makes the aggregator to build new groups for each message, just because message id is always unique.

By the way, you don't need release strategy as well. The aggregator easily do that by the populate `sequenceNumber` header.

And I'm not sure that you need `group-timeout` too.

In other words what you need for your use-case is just rely on the out-of-the-box sequence details feature:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

Comment: I am able to combine the response from publish subscribe channel now. But after adding task executor when i hit the service from soap ui i am getting an empty response. But if i debug and check i find that all methods are getting executed and the response is generated.

Comment: There is something else missed in your description. For example how does it work without task executor. You should be really sure that you carry the `replyChannel` header after aggregation. You always can switch DEBUG on for the `org.springframework.integration` to observe in logs how your messages travel.

Comment: I have added a snippet from my aggregator. Is the issue due my aggregator?

Comment: Well, that's true your aggregation function isn't full. Since Inbound Gateway is based on the `replyChannel` header to wait for the result, that one has to be transferred as well. More over it would be better to transfer all the request headers. You should consider to extend from the `AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor` and just build your custom `payload`. The headers will be combined from all the messages in the group.

Comment: That error means that you lose correlation-related headers before the message reaches an aggregator. We need to see more config on the matter to figure out which step of your flow causes this situation

Comment: Tried by extending AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor . It works well for synchronous implementation when the channels are not defined in the spring configuration file. But after adding the channel definitions I'm getting the below exception: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessa‌​geHandler#0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed. Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing? (Updated the snippet from config file)

Comment: Posted the entire spring configuration file. The configuration works fine without the below:                                                                                   
     <int:channel id="bridgeOutputChannel" />
     <int:aggegator id="aggregatorInput" />
    <int:channel id="aggregatorOutput" />                                                           Only after adding the channel definition I'm facing the issue.

Comment: What is that `aggregator is="aggregatorInput"` about? Why do you need it?

Comment: That is <int:channel id="aggregatorInput" /> not aggregator.  It was replaced somehow while editing.

Comment: Ok, good. So, what debug logs says on the matter? Can you figure out on what step do you loose correlation headers?

Comment: The issue is due to incorrect channel definition,it's fixed.

Comment: Great! Would you mind to share a description of the problem and fix? Also consider to accept my answer if that satisfies an original request

Comment: I was getting  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed. Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing? exception due to channel definition. <int:channel id="bridgeOutputChannel" />. Since bridgeOutputChannel is a publish subscribe channel after removing the the channel definition it worked!