# Aggregator is failing after upgrading to Spring-Integration 4

Tags: spring-integration

We are using Spring-Integration in our project. We are trying to migrate from `spring-integration-core:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE` to `spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE`, `java 8`, `spring 4`. We are running into issues with `aggregator`. Weirdly, the aggregator's method is not called during the execution. The configuration is shown below:

```
        <!-- Store the original payload in header for future purpose -->
    <int:header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
        <int:header name="${headerNames.originalPayload}" expression="payload" />
    </int:header-enricher>  

    <!-- split the issues-->
    <int-xml:xpath-splitter  >
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//transaction"/>
    </int-xml:xpath-splitter>

    <int:service-activator  ref="httpOutboundGatewayHandler" method="buildHttpOutboundGatewayRequest" />

    <int:header-filter  header-names="accept-encoding"/>    

    <int-http:outbound-gateway  url-expression="headers.restResourceUrl"
                                http-method-expression="headers.httpMethod"
                                extract-request-payload="true"
                                expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <int:service-activator ref="msgHandler" method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" />   


    <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQGetWorklist-Response-MoveSources}"  />
</int:chain>    

    <int:aggregator input-channel="PQGetWorklist-Aggregate-sources" output-channel="PQGetWorklist-MoveSourcesUnderIssues"  
                    ref="xmlAggregator"  method="aggregateSources">      
    </int:aggregator>
```

In the above code, `<int-http:outbound-gateway` is getting executed, but the `XmlAggregator.aggregateSources` is not called for unknown reasons. I could see that the message is sent to on the channel `PQGetWorklist-Aggregate-sources`. But from there the `aggregator`'s method `aggregateSources` is not called. As a result, we are getting `No reply received within timeout`. Remember the same configuration is working fine with `spring-integration-core:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE`. The problem is seen only when we upgrade it to `spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE` . 
Here is my `XmlAggregator.java`

```
public class XmlAggregator {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XmlAggregator.class);
    public Message aggregateSources(List < Message > messages) throws DocumentException {
     Document mainDom = XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document("<Results> </Results>");
     Document splitMessageDom = XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document(messages.get(0).getPayload().toString());
     Document IssuesDom = XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document("<Issues> </Issues>");
     Document sourcesDom = XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document("<RetrievedSources> </RetrievedSources>");
     if(messages.get(0).getHeaders().get("jobDesignerJobName").equals("PQIssueInquiry")){
     //extract callerType node
     Element callerType = XmlParserUtil.getXmlElements(XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document(messages.get(0).getPayload().toString()), "//callerType").get(0);
     //add callerType to root node
     mainDom.getRootElement().content().add(callerType);
     }
     //extract sort node
     Element sort = XmlParserUtil.getXmlElements(XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document(messages.get(0).getPayload().toString()), "//sort").get(0);
     //add sort to root node
     mainDom.getRootElement().content().add(sort);

     //get all the issues 
     List < Element > transactionElements = XmlParserUtil.getXmlElements(splitMessageDom, "//transaction");
     for (Element issue: transactionElements) {
      // add all the issues to the IssuesDom
      IssuesDom.getRootElement().content().add(issue);
     }
     //add all the issues to the root node
     XmlParserUtil.appendChild(mainDom, IssuesDom, null);
     for (Message source: messages) {

      Document sourcesTempDom = XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document(source.getPayload().toString());
      Reader xml = new StringReader((String) source.getPayload());
      SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
      Document document = reader.read(xml);
      //get all the sources
      List < Element > sourceElements = XmlParserUtil.getXmlElements(sourcesTempDom, "//sources");

      for (Element sources: sourceElements) {
       //add all the sources to sourcesDom 
       sourcesDom.getRootElement().content().add(sources);
      }

     }

     // add all the sources to the root node
     XmlParserUtil.appendChild(mainDom, sourcesDom, null);

     MessageBuilder < ? > msgBuilder = MessageBuilder.withPayload(mainDom.asXML());
     Message message = msgBuilder.build();
     logger.debug("aggregateSources Results after aggregation " + mainDom.asXML());
     return message;
    }

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to show the `xmlAggregator` class.

Comment: @GaryRussell, Thanks for the response. I have added the `XmlAggregator.java` to the question. Please take a look now.

Comment: Looks like you have the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069611/how-to-make-aggregator-wait-for-response-from-all-methods-in-publish-subsribe-ch: you have to copy all the headers to the output message. Or just don't return a `Message<?>` from  your `aggregateSources()`. I see that `mainDom.asXML()`  is fully enough to proceed. The Framework will take care about proper message building for you then. See `MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor` which is used in this case.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, Out of curiosity, why it was working without any issue with the lower version of Spring-Integration then?

Comment: Well, there might be has changed a lot since there. For example there is no reason to re-create message, if the reply is already message - some kind of optimization. Although I might be wrong with the `AggregatingMessageHandler`. Would be great if you can switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` and take a look into logs how your messages are traveling and what header do they carry

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I turned on `DEBUG` already and verified that the message is carrying all the  headers. Do you want me to verify anything related `aggregator` in the headers? I could see that the message is sent to on the channel `PQGetWorklist-Aggregate-sources`. The next expected channel where the message should be passed is `PQGetWorklist-MoveSourcesUnderIssues`. But the channel `PQGetWorklist-MoveSourcesUnderIssues` is never reached since `XmlAggregator.aggregateSources()` is not called.

Comment: Hm. Can see `correlationId`, `sequenceNumber` and `sequenceSize` headers? I wonder if we lose them during `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` invocation... In that case the aggregator doesn't know how to correlate your message to groups.

Comment: I could see `sequenceDetails=[[59d720b4-542d-eb08-3050-be4f14e9c102, 1, 0], [5863ec8a-6f3f-cab5-2425-f1abcb5e9103, 1, 0]], 
`  .......`correlationId=aee24a83-a7ab-625f-ad56-a722544f3902, id=7bb6f4cf-a89c-d522-20ed-d541048aa639, `.....`sequenceNumber=10` and `sequenceSize=0`.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, But when we use lower version of spring-integration, i could see different values.. sequenceNumber=10,sequenceSize=10. But why `sequenceSize` is not `10` when we migrate to Spring 4?

Comment: Good catch, @Ashok.N ! See my answer on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version `4.2` the `XPathMessageSplitter` is based on the `iterator` functionality by default:

```
<xsd:attribute name="iterator" default="true">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            The iterator mode: 'true' (default) to return an 'java.util.Iterator'
            for splitting 'payload', 'false to return a 'java.util.List'.
            Note: the 'list' contains transformed nodes whereas with the
            'iterator' each node is transformed while iterating.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string" />
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

Do not overhead the memory with the `size` interest and pull the data from the target source on demand.

The functionality can be turned off via `iterator="false"` option.

Comment: So  changing to  `<int-xml:xpath-splitter iterator="false"  > `would solve that `aggreagator` issue. (OR) `XmlAggregator.java ` code needs to be modified if we have the default behavior for `XPathMessageSplitter `. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The `aggregator` is good here with its default strategy. Only the `iterator="false"` should be added to the `<int-xml:xpath-splitter>` to revert to the previous behavior and there fore populate `sequenceSize` with the real amount of splitted nodes.

Comment: But my IDE is showing error `iterator="false"
 is not allowd on xpath-splitter`. What's wrong here?

Comment: Wrong IDE. Just compile the project and see what's going on. You should configure your Eclipse to resolve Spring XSDs from classpath, not the Internet.

Comment: Okay.. I will do that.. I am currently using `IntelliJ`

Comment: Yes..You are correct.. It's the problem with the IDE. `Aggregator` issue resolved now. It would be great if the change related to `XPathMessageSplitter` is added in the migration guide. Plus one for your continuous support.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.1-to-4.2-Migration-Guide#xpath-splitter

Comment: It would be much useful if add  the same thing in the migration guide from 3 to 4 . I mean here:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/spring-integration-3.0-to-4.0-migration-guide

Comment: Well, since you jump from `3.0` to `4.3`, you really should consult all the migration steps from version to version.